# react-native useFocusEffect "holdings" is read-only error

Tags: react-native

react-native useFocusEffect "holdings" is read-only error

```
const Home = ({ getHoldings, getCoinMarket, myHoldings, coins }) => {   
    useFocusEffect(
        React.useCallback(() => {
            getHoldings(holdings=dummyData.holdings)
            getCoinMarket()
        })
    )
```

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b45k.png)

Comment: In this line getHoldings(holdings=dummyData.holdings) you are both calling a function getHoldings and setting the value of the holdings variable to dummyData.holdings.  It’s unclear what you are trying to do, but you probably want getHoldings(dummyData.holdings).

Comment: Thank you. this was the problem.